# Getting error: Formula Expression is required on the action attributes

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller

I have created a vf page with Contact standard controller to create a Contact record.

User will create record in vf page and should be redirected to the related Contact detail page created.
Here is the vf page sample code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="onboardform">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:outputPanel id="EntryForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>First Name:</b>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!con.FirstName}" style="width:225px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Last Name:</b>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!con.LastName}" style="width:225px;" required="true" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submit}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller Code:

```
public class onboardform {
    public Contact con {get;set;}
    String conId;
    String stdcon;
    public onboardform(ApexPages.StandardController stdcon) {
        conId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        if (conId != null && conId != '') // if id is in url means record is for edit 
            con = (Contact) stdcon.getRecord();
        else // else you r gonna create new record
            con = new Contact();
    }
    public PageReference submit() {
        if (conId != null && conId != '')
            update con;
        else {
            Contact newContact = new Contact();
            newContact.FirstName = con.FirstName;
            newContact.LastName = con.LastName;
            newContact.HUB_ID__c = con.HUB_ID__c;
            newContact.Approver_Requestor__c = con.Approver_Requestor__c;
            insert newContact;
            conId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
            PageReference requestPage = new pagereference(+newContact.id);
            return requestPage;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I am entering the details in the vf page , the contact is getting created but not redirected to the related contact detail standard salesforce page and getting error msg

> Formula Expression is required on the action attributes

Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Comment: You didn't even *need* a controller for this page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pagereference method has an issue not returning right parameters .

The modified code is as below

```
 public PageReference submit()
     {
       if(conId != null && conId!='')
       update con;
        else
        {
        Contact newContact = new Contact();
        newContact.FirstName = con.FirstName;
        newContact.LastName = con.LastName;
        insert newContact;
        conId = newContact.id;

        } 
       PageReference requestPage = new pagereference('/'+conId); //Observe the change here .The Id needs to be populated 
        return requestPage;  
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit!!
I tried this earlier...unfortunaltely I missed the '/' before +newContact.id :)

Comment: See valuable comment from sfdcfox that you do not need a controller if its just inserting contact record .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, his code will not work on update

Comment: @SantanuBoral I am not sure what asker wants on update :) .But if asker wants to refresh ,I agree he needs to remove null and add a pagereference instead

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, thats true. Thats why I have tried to make it workable for insert and update.

Comment: @SantanuBoral I just updated my answer but feel sfdcfox is correct to use just standard controller if updates and inserts are only thing user needs apart from styling .Also +1 for your answer .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava sfdcfox is correct here

Answer (score 3):

Don't use an extension unless you need to. You can reduce your entire page to just:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.FirstName}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LastName}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This automatically handles inserts and updates, will display error messages if something goes wrong (e.g. a required field is not set), and will redirect to the contact record after saving. Feel free to change the style if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the code and return the PageReference as follows:

```
public class onboardform
{
    public Contact con{get; set;}
    String conId;
    String stdcon;
    public onboardform(ApexPages.StandardController stdcon) {

     //conId=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); 
     conId = stdcon.getId();
     if(conId != null && conId!='') 
     {                            // if id is in url means record is for edit 
         con= [SELECT FirstName, LastName, HUB_ID__c,Approver_Requestor__c  FROM Contact WHERE Id=:conId];
     }
      else                                                      // else you r gonna create new record
      con=new Contact();

    }
 public PageReference submit()
     {
       if(conId != null && conId!='')
       {
          update con; 
       }
        else
        {
            Contact newContact = new Contact();
            newContact.FirstName = con.FirstName;
            newContact.LastName = con.LastName;
            newContact.HUB_ID__c = con.HUB_ID__c;
            newContact.Approver_Requestor__c = con.Approver_Requestor__c;
            insert newContact;
            conId = newContact.Id;
        } 
       PageReference requestPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(new Contact(Id=conId)).view();
        return requestPage;
     }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error after the changing the page reference as suggested!!

Comment: I have tested and modified your code, there was a problem during update also which I have fixed.

Comment: Thanks Santanu for pointing out the update issue.Really appreciate your help:)

Comment: Atleast put some mark, fixed your code properly to work both insert and update